# CSS display:inline animation not working using jquery addClass

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/iggPen/pen/QMVyrp

If you notice, there are two animations: `reveal-sandwich` and `large-expansion`. I could not get `reveal-sandwich` animation to work.

This is the jquery:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  $('.container').addClass('animate_sandwich');
  $(this).addClass('large-expansion');
})
```

The idea is when I click a button, it will animate both `.container` and `.button`. I want the container to reveal (`display: inline;`). However, when I click the button, it is not displaying. 
I know I can achieve the same without `animation`. I can just put `display: inline` inside `.animate_sandwich` class, but I am planning to add more animation in addition to `display: inline`, it is imperative that I get it to work via animation.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `display` property can't be animated. To get the effect you're looking for, you can animate the `opacity` property:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  background: $sandwich_container;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: inline;
  opacity: 0;
}

.animate_sandwich {
  animation: reveal-sandwich 1s ease-out 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes reveal-sandwich {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  50% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QMVEYw)

Comment: Got it. I never knew that. I guess that makes sense, because display doesn't accept numerical values - makes no sense to have `@keyframes` `display: none/inline/ block/ &c`. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! That's a nice looking burger btw :)

Comment: Thanks!! My wife works at this franchise, so I wanted to do something fun for her :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot animate the `display` property.

You can use `opacity` if you want to animate it:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/brxeOX

This is the change to your css:

```
.container {
  ...
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline;
}


@keyframes reveal-sandwich {
    0% {opacity: 0}
    50% {opacity: 100;}
    100% {opacity: 100;}
}
```